# Which is the best way to add Google Calendar API scope for GCE service account used by docker container?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-calendar-api, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

Which is the best way to add Google Calendar scope/permissions to a service account used by an application (Spring Boot) running inside a container in a Google Compute Engine Container-Optimized OS?

I have read similar SO's but without success and many didn't run docker inside their GCE or didn't use the Google Calendar API. Also, I have enabled the Calendar API for my cloud project but didn't help.

When I start up a GCE COS instance with my Spring Boot container it doesn't seem to have the required scope for the Google Calendar API since I get a 403 Forbidden whenever my application tries to use the calendar API.

```
403 Forbidden POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/test@gmail.com/events
```

test@gmail.com in this case is already configured to allow requests from the default service account that my GCE is using, but it still results in 403.

Here is the code for where my Spring Boot configures a GoogleCredentials:

```
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));
HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials);
this.client = new Calendar.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), new GsonFactory(), requestInitializer).setApplicationName("AppName").build();
```

and this triggers the error:

```
client.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

The only way I managed to fix this was to update the scopes of the default service account used by my GCE with gcloud:

```
gcloud compute instances set-service-account <gce instance name> --service-account someunique_id@developer.gserviceaccount.com --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar,<more scopes...>
```

However, this must be done for each created instance and the service account cannot be used by any running instance if one needs to update the scopes for the newly created instance. Is there a better way or a different way to get calendar scope and permissions for a docker container inside a GCE?

**Note:** Strangely enough, when I copy the service account credential JSON and use it locally it works. Shouldn't this be the exact same service account which my docker container is using and if so, why doesn't it work inside GCE?